# how to integrate juju for use hpcloud

Tags: juju

Kindly guide me through to configure environments.yaml file for hpcloud so that juju shall access HPCloud for deploying instances.

thanks,

Guru

Answer (score 0):

The information on how to configure Juju for its usage with HPCloud can be found [here](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-hpcloud.html) (https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-hpcloud.html).